# Emacs shell behavior

Tags: emacs

I am using cygwin on windows 7. I have a question regarding the Emacs shell.

Whenever I use the shell inside of the Emacs(M-x shell)
It echo pwd directory after prints out the result.
I found it very annoying since it distracts me.

e.g.

```
$ ls
workspace
^[]0;~/cs61bl^G
myname@pc ~/cs61bl
```

Is there any way to remove these lines?

```
^[]0;~/cs61bl^G 
myname@pc ~/cs61bl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Emacs, try using the eshell:  `M-x eshell`.  The eshell does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would guess it's because you are proposing an alternative solution instead of answering the question.  Especially because "It is much better" is subjective.  This probably should have just been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for "shell-dirtrack-mode". You can either do an `M-x shell-dirtrack-toggle` or `(shell-dirtrack-mode 1)` in your init file. Recent emacs versions seem to disable it by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is this file http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/setup-cygwin.el that simplifies setup of various packages in Emacs (including shell) to use cygwin. Also try not to use ANSI sequences in your PS1 prompt because Emacs shell mode wouldn't interpret them, something like

```
export PS1="\h \W\$ "
```

should do.